# Get nested XML output sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a problem with my xml output from sql server database. My table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_table](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [firstname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [city] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [street] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [streetno] [int] NULL
)
```

I want the output, where Address is nested inside each Person, like this:

```
<Root>
  <Person id="1">
    <firstname>Stefanie</firstname>
    <lastname>Buckley</lastname>
    <Address>
      <city>Oklahoma</city>
      <street> Cowley Road</street>
      <streetno>34</streetno>
    </Address>
  </Person>
  <Person id="2">
    <firstname>Sandy</firstname>
    <lastname>Mc Gee</lastname>
    <Address>
      <city>Montgomery</city>
      <street> Hague Parkway</street>
      <streetno>27</streetno>
    </Address>
  </Person>
</Root>
```

I've tried with nested select like:

```
 select tbl1.id '@id', tbl1.firstname, tbl1.lastname,
 (
 select city,street,streetno from test_table as tbl2
 where tbl2.id = tbl1.id
 for xml path('Address')
 ) 
 from test_table as tbl1
 for xml path('Person'), Root('Root')
```

but the output is like:

```
<Root>
  <Person id="1">
    <firstname>Stefanie</firstname>
    <lastname>Buckley</lastname>&lt;Address&gt;&lt;city&gt;Oklahoma&lt;/city&gt;&lt;street&gt; Cowley Road&lt;/street&gt;&lt;streetno&gt;34&lt;/streetno&gt;&lt;/Address&gt;</Person>
  <Person id="2">
    <firstname>Sandy</firstname>
    <lastname>Mc Gee</lastname>&lt;Address&gt;&lt;city&gt;Anchorage&lt;/city&gt;&lt;street&gt; North Green Clarendon Road&lt;/street&gt;&lt;streetno&gt;29&lt;/streetno&gt;&lt;/Address&gt;</Person>
  <Person id="3">
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot `, type` and you don't need wxtra reading from table.

```
select tbl1.id '@id'
    , tbl1.firstname
    , tbl1.lastname
    , (
        select city
            , street
            , streetno
        for xml path('Address'), type
    ) 
from test_table as tbl1
for xml path('Person'), type, Root('Root')
```

Comment: It works! One thing is not clear to me: if I don't use type on the outer query - for xml path('Person'), /*no type here*/, Root('Root'), the output is the same as if I use the type keyword. Why is that? What is the main purpose of type keyword?

Comment: The output is the same but without type directive it is text, not xml:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190025(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: See this example: `select (select 1 'c' for xml path('a')/*, type*/, root('b') ) + 'zzz'`